# What's wrong with my delete link?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

```
<%= link_to "Delete Party", party_path(@party.id), :method => :delete %>
```

a GET is always called according to the logs. I just get redirected to the same show page when I click the delete link.

Comment: I figured it out. I needed to get a new rails.js file. I'm not sure why JS is needed to make a delete HTTP request.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of @party.id, use @party in party_path().

Answer (score 0):

The solution worked for me..
I was using `jQuery 1.4.4` and facing issues with the delete link, I read somewhere about the jQuery version issue and switched to `jQuery 1.4.2` and delete link worked fine for me.